# Installed Ubuntu server 23.10 using debootstrap / chroot - on boot it fails to mount the correct root partition

Tags: ubuntu, installation, chroot, debootstrap

I'm trying to work out a process for remote installation of Ubuntu Server. I want to have someone at the other end insert a flash drive and boot up, then I will ssh in and install.

Here's the process I have worked out so far, based mostly on [this blog post](https://semjonov.de/posts/2021-09/minimal-ubuntu-installation-with-debootstrap/):

1. Log in to the installer system using ssh.
2. Partition the hard drives:

- sda, sdb, and sdc - Three identical hard drives each with

  - a 500M vfat partition for EFI, and
  - the rest partitioned for RAID1 (md127).
- md127 - two partitions,

  - /boot formatted as ext4, and
  - crypt_root encrypted using luksFormat
- crypt_root

  - / - A single logical volume (LVM) formatted as ext4 (/dev/mapper/vgroot-vroot)

`sda                      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk`

`├─sda1                   8:1    0   476M  0 part`

`└─sda2                   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part`

`└─md127                9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid1`

`├─md127p1          259:0    0   9.3G  0 part`

`└─md127p2          259:1    0   1.8T  0 part`

`└─crypt_root     252:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt`

`└─vgroot-vroot 252:1    0   1.8T  0 lvm`

3. Mount the filesystems (mnt/, mnt/boot, and mnt/boot/efi)
4. Install the base system: `sudo debootstrap mantic mnt http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`
5. Generate fstab:

`sudo su - root -s /bin/bash -c 'genfstab -U /home/installer/mnt >> /home/installer/mnt/etc/fstab'`

6. Set up mnt/etc/crypttab:

`crypt_root    UUID=...    none    luks`

7. Set up mnt/etc/apt/sources.list:

`deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic main universe`

`deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security main universe`

`deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates main universe`

8. chroot into the new system: `sudo arch-chroot mnt`
9. Install ubuntu-server and some other packages, start ssh, add a sudo user, set up networking.
10. Set up EFI:

`update-initramfs -u`

`bootctl install`

`cp --dereference /boot/vmlinuz /boot/initrd.img boot/efi/`

11. Clone the EFI partitions:

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 status=progress`

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1 status=progress`

12. Use efibootmgr to remove the installer system (flash drive) and add sdb1 and sdc1
13. Exit chroot, shut down, remove the flash drive, and start up.

On boot, I get a prompt for the encrypted drive's passphrase, which works, then when the system tries to load the root partition, it fails with the message 'UUID=... does not exist.' The UUID in the error message matches the root partition of the flash drive. I checked /etc/fstab and it has the correct UUID. How can I apply the correct configuration to the bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to change the EFI setup (step 11):

```
update-initramfs -u
bootctl install
```

Then edit the configuration file at /boot/efi/loader/entries/....conf and change the root UUID in the boot options (the correct UUID can be found in /etc/fstab)

I didn't need to copy vmlinuz or initrd.img